# remove from elasticsearch not existing in DB(mongoDB) elements

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

How I can remove from **elasticsearch** not existing in DB(mongoDB) elements?
It will be great if solution on Node.js.
I use **mongoosastic**, but it is not a problem for another packages.

Comment: It seems like the only solution will be going through all records in Elasticsearch and delete if record doesn't exist.

Comment: I believed that exist some better solution. Thank you.

Comment: you can do it in batches :)